# How can I make a matrix form when $\Bbb{R}^3 \to \Bbb{R}^4$ is one-to-one?

Tags: linear-transformations

> Problem : if $T: \Bbb{R}^3\to \Bbb{R}^4$ is one-to-one, describe the possible
>   echelon forms of the standard matrix for a linear transformation $T$.

My solution is below.

To be one-to-one every column vectors must be independent, it means every columns must have pivot position. So I can form like this.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a&*&*\\
0&b&*\\
0&0&c\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Am I right? If not, how can I approach this problem?

Comment: Yes, $T$ is injective if and only if $\operatorname{rank}(T) = 3$, which is true if and only if it is similar to a matrix of the above form.

Comment: @mechanodroid I didn't learn about "injective" and "$\text{rank}(T)$" yet, can you explain?

Comment: Injective means one-to-one. Rank is the number of linearly independent columns (or rows) of $T$.

Comment: Thx for the explanation.

Comment: You need nonzero $a$, $b$ and $c$.